# Post the value from js to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

EDİTED("I think that i should use Ajax how can i do it")I created comboboxes dynamically.  When I want to get the value from the textbox, I can't post to PHP. Here is my code:

**HTML code:**

```
<form method="post" name="sigortayap" action="sigorta-process.php" onsubmit="return a()" >
   <select id="yetiskinid" class="selectTravelInputFieldsCar" name="yetiskin" onChange="yetiskintext()" >
    <option value="-1">Seçiniz</option>                 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option> 
    </select>     
    <div id="yetiskindiv"></div>

</form>
```

**JS Code:**

```
function yetiskintext() {
var secenek=document.getElementById("yetiskinid").value;

    while (secenek>0){
   var textBoxname = document.createElement('input');
    textBoxname.name = 'textyetiskinname'+secenek;
    textBoxname.id='textyetiskinname'+secenek;
    textBoxname.type = 'text';
    textBoxname.className='selectTravelInputFieldsCarJS';
    document.getElementById("yetiskindiv").appendChild(textBoxname);
    }
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php   
   $kece=htmlspecialchars($_POST["textyetiskinname1"]);     
   echo $kece; 
?>
```

When I put `echo $kece;` in the PHP, I can't see any output. Why?

Comment: There is no post in JS

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST)` in your PHP code and look what it will display.

Comment: add a submit button in your form

Comment: `getElementById("yetiskinid")` - shouldn't this be `getElementById(yetiskinid)` or `getElementById("yetiskindiv")`?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the combobox is `'textyetiskinname'+secenek` not `'textyetiskinname'`. You miss the number at the end of the name.
Maybe you should try this:

```
textBoxname.setAttribute("name", 'textyetiskinname['+secenek+']');
```

instead of `.name`

Comment: @user3154558 What data do you have in your $_POST array? please provide the output of `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: @Megioco see updated answer. And yes, try to close your <select> tag before the div.

Comment: i think that i should try different thing

Comment: @Megioco did you have some data in your $_POST array? Did you try var_dump($_POST)? Can you provide us this output?

Comment: @Megioco I created a fiddle for this case. It works: http://jsfiddle.net/zafLM/ But your example can't work with `while (secenek>0){` , it should be `if (secenek>0){`

Comment: when i tried  var_dump($_POST) writing 'NULL' can you explain details of it and where is the php code in  jsfiddle.net/zafLM ?

Comment: @Megioco the PHP code is on my test server, you can see the path in the form param "action". You also have a value in this param: `sigorta-process.php` - this should be you target script that contains the $_POST handling. And where did you try to handle the data?

Comment: should i add somthing in js ? in php codes $kece=var_dump($_POST["textyetiskinname1"]); i try to get value like this but return 'NULL' or add something in php code ?

Comment: @Megioco `var_dump()` only prints the structure of given object - so you can see what params do you have in the $_POST array like this: `array(2) { ["yetiskin"]=> string(1) "1" ["textyetiskinname1"]=> string(6) "asdasd" }`. Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zafLM/4/ . If you set the combobox name to an array you can better read this value in your PHP file by `$kece=htmlspecialchars($_POST["textyetiskinname"]); // that should be an array with only one entry`